# Retrieving data matching the specified Pattern on XML Datatype

Tags: xml

How can I retrieve all the LastNames like '%e%' ?

Required Output

```
Desai, Pandey
```

My XML:

```
DECLARE @MyXml XML  --declaring a variable of XML Datatype
SET @MyXml=' <Employees>
   <Employee>
      <Empid Status="On Vacation">1</Empid>
      <FirstName>Tejas</FirstName>
      <LastName>Desai</LastName>
      <Age>21</Age>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
      <Empid Status="Active">2</Empid>
      <FirstName>Manohar</FirstName>
      <LastName>Pandey</LastName>
      <Age>34</Age>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
      <Empid Status="Left">3</Empid>
      <FirstName>Anis</FirstName>
      <LastName>Shaikh</LastName>
      <Age>45</Age> </Employee>
</Employees>'
```

Three rows have been assigned to the variable each having four column values

Need to display all the names that match the pattern = '%e%'

The below query throws error

```
select @MyXml.query ('data(/Employees/Employee[@FirstName like '%e%'])')
```

Comment: Well, ***WHAT*** error does your query cause? Please post the complete and accurate error! We really cannot read your screen - nor your mind ....

Comment: Also: if you check for **FirstName** containing an `e` - your result would be `Tejas` only - right?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
-- define a CTE to extract the relevant info from the <Employee> nodes
;WITH XmlCte AS 
(
    SELECT
        EmpId = XC.value('(Empid)[1]', 'int'),
        FirstName = XC.value('(FirstName)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
        LastName = XC.value('(LastName)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
        Age = XC.value('(Age)[1]', 'int')
    FROM
        @myxml.nodes('/Employees/Employee') AS XT(XC)
)
-- select from that CTE and get those employees with a 'e' in their last name
SELECT *
FROM XmlCte
WHERE LastName LIKE '%e%'
```

Or if you want the employees with their first name containing an `e`, use:

```
SELECT *
FROM XmlCte
WHERE FirstName LIKE '%e%'
```